# CSS button position below the text in Media query

Tags: css, html, media-queries

In my responsive webpage. On that page I have text and then there is a button. The problem is button moves on text when I resize the page. 
The button needs to be below text and should remain below text as I resize the page.

If you copy and paste the code in HTML, and then try to resize the page, you would see button does change size (as I need) but the location of the button is not ok. It goes on text

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <style>
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 300px) {
 #Space_I { height:28px;} 
 #Space_J { height:22px;} 
 #Space_K { height:3%;} 
 #Main_Title {
  width: auto; 
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 1.04;
  color: #222222;
  margin-left:6%;
  margin-right:6%;
 }
 #First_Blog{
  height: 100px;
 }
 #First_Read_More_Button{
  width: 291px;
  height: 45px    
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 500px) {
 #Space_I { height:33px;} 
 #Space_J { height:26px;} 
 #Space_K { height:3%;} 
 #Main_Title{
   width: auto;
   height: 36px;
   font-size: 31px;
   color: #000000;
   margin-left:5%;
   margin-right:5%;
 }
 #First_Blog{
  height: 120px;
 }
 #First_Read_More_Button{
  width: 167px;
  height: 45px;
 }
 
}
body {    
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wholepage" style="margin: auto;">
   <div class="container" >
     <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <span id="Space_I" style="display:block"></span>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <div id="Main_Title" style="font-family: Arial;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
           14 Best travel hacks for globetrotters
          </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <span id="Space_J" style="display:block"></span>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <div id="First_Blog" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 1.5;text-align: center;color: #222222;">
           <p style="margin-left:6%;margin-right:6%;text-align:justify">As fantastic as traveling is, it can be stressful at times – you have to pack and keep track of everything you need while navigating a new environment. But fear not, friends. We collected 14 travel hacks that will help you MacGyver your next trip: we tell you why you should always use the shower caps in hotel rooms, why you need to buy diapers even if you don’t have a baby, and why dryer sheets are best used before doing laundry. And that’s only the beginning. </p>
          </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <span id="Space_K" style="display:block"></span>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <div style="text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">
           <button id="First_Read_More_Button" style="border-radius: 100px;border: solid 0.8px #00a4c3;">Read More</button>
          </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>   
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The read more button needs to below the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the height you are applying to `#First_Blog`. By specifying a height the content is overflowing and going above the button.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  #Space_I {
    height: 28px;
  }
  #Space_J {
    height: 22px;
  }
  #Space_K {
    height: 3%;
  }
  #Main_Title {
    width: auto;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 1.04;
    color: #222222;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-right: 6%;
  }
  #First_Read_More_Button {
    width: 291px;
    height: 45px
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 500px) {
  #Space_I {
    height: 33px;
  }
  #Space_J {
    height: 26px;
  }
  #Space_K {
    height: 3%;
  }
  #Main_Title {
    width: auto;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 31px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  }
  #First_Read_More_Button {
    width: 167px;
    height: 45px;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wholepage" style="margin: auto;">
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span id="Space_I" style="display:block"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="Main_Title" style="font-family: Arial;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                14 Best travel hacks for globetrotters
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span id="Space_J" style="display:block"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="First_Blog" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 15px;line-height: 1.5;text-align: center;color: #222222;">
                <p style="margin-left:6%;margin-right:6%;text-align:justify">As fantastic as traveling is, it can be stressful at times – you have to pack and keep track of everything you need while navigating a new environment. But fear not, friends. We collected 14 travel hacks that will help you MacGyver your
                  next trip: we tell you why you should always use the shower caps in hotel rooms, why you need to buy diapers even if you don’t have a baby, and why dryer sheets are best used before doing laundry. And that’s only the beginning. </p>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span id="Space_K" style="display:block"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div style="text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">
                <button id="First_Read_More_Button" style="border-radius: 100px;border: solid 0.8px #00a4c3;">Read More</button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

By the way you can simplify your code as you don't need the table structure and all theses media queries. You can simply make it like this and play with padding/margin for spacing :

```css
#First_Blog {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222222;
  margin: 20px 6%;
  text-align: justify;
}

#Main_Title {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 1.04;
  color: #222222;
  margin: 50px 6% 0;
}

#First_Read_More_Button {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid 0.8px #00a4c3;
  width: 291px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="Main_Title">
  14 Best travel hacks for globetrotters
</div>
<div id="First_Blog">
  <p>As fantastic as traveling is, it can be stressful at times – you have to pack and keep track of everything you need while navigating a new environment. But fear not, friends. We collected 14 travel hacks that will help you MacGyver your next trip: we
    tell you why you should always use the shower caps in hotel rooms, why you need to buy diapers even if you don’t have a baby, and why dryer sheets are best used before doing laundry. And that’s only the beginning. </p>
</div>
<button id="First_Read_More_Button">Read More</button>
```